# is React Native for web ready for production

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Should I use react-native-web just yet? Everything looks ok to me except for the router. For reference https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: I'd say it depends on a use case. We've been using it in our production for about a year now. Expect to lose some hair while working with it tho ;)

Comment: @VilleKoo the app will have camera upload, data visualization. I think for things that the web don't support, a separate component can be created for the web only. What about the router support? the example site's router doesn't support browser back button.

Comment: Yeah we've been using camera with our app too, so it's definitely doable. The thing is that we don't use react-native-web in a traditional browser, instead we have a chromeless browser in our app (we don't have to worry about back button). Like I said, depends on use case :)